# No enviar el mismo input muchas veces (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular, angular5, rxjs

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fc.tipoDato === 79">
  <ng-container *ngIf="fc.catalogoCompendio === 450 && comboTipoSuministrado">
    <app-input-filtro class="col-xs-8" [form]="form" [fc]="fc" [combo]=comboTipoSuministrado
      [operadores]="operadores.operadoresCuanti.json">
    </app-input-filtro>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="fc.catalogoCompendio === 450 && !comboTipoSuministrado">
    <!-- <input type="number" formControlName="valor1"> -->
    <app-input-filtro class="col-xs-8" [form]="form" [fc]="fc" [combo]=comboTipoSuministrado
      [operadores]="operadores.operadoresCuanti.blanco">
    </app-input-filtro>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="fc.catalogoCompendio === 449">
    <app-input-filtro class="col-xs-8" [form]="form" [fc]="fc" [combo]=comboVariableCatalogo
      [operadores]="operadores.operadoresCuanti.json">
    </app-input-filtro>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="fc.catalogoCompendio === 448">
    <app-input-filtro class="col-xs-8" [form]="form" [fc]="fc" [combo]=comboTipoCatalogo
      [operadores]="operadores.operadoresCuanti.json">
    </app-input-filtro>
  </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

En todos los casos envio el mismo [form]="form" y eso hace que mi componente hijo reciba muchos inputs repetidos, solo necesito uno. ¿Cual sería la mejor forma de resolver este problema?

Comment: `comboTipoCatalogo`, `comboVariableCatalogo`, `comboTipoSuministrado`, `comboTipoSuministrado`, provienen de una api o tu los rellenas con información. 
Podrias agregar más información por favor.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si esto resolvera tu problema pero capaz esta ingresando a todas las sentencias *ngIf porque estas utilizando los 3 signos de igual, proba cambiar "===" por "==" que seria la manera correcta de escribirlo, espero te sirva.